# How to sing properly with a low larynx?

Tags: technique, voice, physiology

Changing the larynx position during singing is beneficial in order to archieve certain timbres. A hightened larynx is often caused by excess tension, so from this perspective alone, it can be beneficial to be able to lower the larynx. It is often advised not to lower the larynx actively, because it might result in strain in the tongue pressing the larynx down. Rather, it is suggested to assume a yawning poseture in order to lower the larynx. I know that there is the tongue and there are some muscles below the larynx that can pull it down. Now, when I yawn, I feel a significant hardening of my tongue root. However, if I lower the larynx by will, this tensening is also noticeable, but there is clearly less of it. Obviously I've learned successfully to address the muscles below the larynx more strongly while keeping the tongue more or less relaxed. So my questions are:

1. Is this the good way of lowering the larynx - to tighten the muscles below it while keeping the tongue relaxed? Should the focus be on stretching and relaxing the tongue, as you could do it with any muscle in order to become more flexible? Or is it a combination of both?
2. Which strategy do you think is best in achieving more freedom for the larynx in a healthy way?
3. How far is it even possible to lower the larynx without engaging or tensening the tongue? As the tongue is connected to the larynx, pulling it down will also stretch the tongue and cause some counter-tension.

Comment: In my experience the most important thing in having a low larynx is good posture and well balanced activation of the intracostal muscles.  Thinking about the larynx itself is an act of desperation

Comment: I can have a good poseture and still sing with a high larynx if I want to. I'm so tired of this vague and metaphoric advice, all those restrictions on free thought and the fear of analysing and properly understanding the singing process. Metaphoric images can be helpful, as long as one is not able to adress the proper muscles and to perceive what is actually going on in the body. But when you have these awesome accurate tools, you wouldn't continue to use a child's language, right? Where does this belief, that anyone who wants to go further must be desperate come from?

Comment: "I can have a good posture and still sing with a high larynx if I want to": of course.  But for me at least the converse is not true. If I notice my larynx being high, the best solution is generally to focus on posture and breathing. The larynx then takes care of itself. That's not a metaphor, just anatomy. By "thinking about the larynx itself is an act of desperation" I mean that when singing, if focusing on posture and breathing does not help larynx problems, thinking explicitly about the larynx may bring short term relief but makes it worse in the long run, so I only do it when desperate.